# How reference Qt Creator current build directory from Qt project file?

Tags: qt, qmake

Does Qt Creator set a qmake variable containing the build directory that can be referenced from the Qt project file?

The Qt Creator Default build directory:

```
../build-%{CurrentProject:Name}-%{CurrentKit:FileSystemName}-%{CurrentBuild:Name}
```

My goal is to copy the dll's import lib from the build output using QMAKE_POST_LINK to make it easier for my client project to link with.  QMAKE_POST_LINK works if I hard code the path of the import lib.

For example:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy C:\projects\ICP\sw\icpts\sandbox\configurable-system-test-io\build-lib-configurable-system-test-io-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_MSVC2012_32bit_eb09a8-Debug\debug\*.lib  ..\my-lib
```

**Solution:**
Solution provided by fbucek to use $$OUT_DIR solved my problem.  Thank You!

- Under Windows, you must use $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD) in the QMAKE_POST_LINK to convert Unix '/' path characters to Windows '\' path characters.
- To add multiple commands to QMAKE_POST_LINK, enclose in $$quote() with appended $$escape_expand(\n).

Example of Multiple QMAKE_POST_LINK commands:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /Y $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\debug\*.dll  ..\lib$$escape_expand(\\n))
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /Y $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\debug\*.lib  ..\lib$$escape_expand(\\n))
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(copy /Y $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD)\debug\*.pdb  ..\lib$$escape_expand(\\n))
```

Thanks again for $$OUT_PWD !

-Ed

- Qt Creator 2.7.2
- Qt 5.1
- Microsoft VS 2012
- Windows 7

Comment: Though your question is not clear to me but I knew Creator provides under Projects->BuildSettings check shadow build option it allows to change build dir

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes it does**

Put this in pro file, run qmake and check if it shows what you want

```
message($$OUT_PWD)
```

[Qmake Variable Reference OUT_PWD](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#out_pwd)

Then you can use it like this: ( I hope - not tested )

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy $$OUT_PWD\debug\*.lib  ..\my-lib
```

Comment: Thank you for $$OUT_PWD ! I need to read the qmake variable reference line-by-line add a message statement for every one to understand what they do.

Comment: QMAKE_POST_LINK doe not seem to like variables.  I tried:  QMAKE_POST_LINK = copy /Y "$$OUT_PWD\\debug\\*.lib" "..\\lib"

Comment: The problem is $$OUT_PWD uses forward slashes in the path '/' which makes the Windows copy command used by QMAKE_POST_LINK result in the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect.".  Hmmm...

Comment: Use of $$shell_path($$OUT_PWD) solves the forward slash '/' path  problem.  Thanks again!